# Using OR Logical functions with SUMIFS in Excel

Tags: excel, logical-operators

I have two workbooks in excel which I copy columns from one to the other.
I would like to copy the number of one column, say A, IF another column, say B, is equal to "Test Tool" or "Hard Tool". I've written this code and can't get it to work, it just gives me the sum zero which is wrong. The last argument doesn't matter so ignore it.

```
"=SUMIFS('Tooling forecast template'!R6C17:R500C17,'Tooling forecast template'!R6C7:R500C7,""OR(=Test Tool, =Hard Tool)"" ,'Tooling forecast template'!R6C6:R500C6,""<>Actual tool/equipment change"")"
```

Comment: Questions are easier to digest if simplified to their essential elements. An equivalent example that skips the sheet references, uses simpler cell references, and avoids unused arguments is preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 =IF(OR(CellToCheck="Test Tool", CellToCheck="Hard Tool"), CellToCopy, 0)
```

Comment: Ok, so how would you insert that code into mine? I have a SUMIFS function.

Comment: Put that function in another column (hidden if you like) - and then point the SUMIFs expression at the new column

Comment: Sure, that was not exactly what I was looking for but I think its as close to the solution as I can get, I give you the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method that saves you typing out a large number of SUMIF statements, although it doesn't stop Excel having to calculate the multiple SUMIFs...

```
=SUM( SUMIFS('Tooling forecast template'!R6C17:R500C17,'Tooling forecast template'!R6C7:R500C7, {"Test Tool", "Hard Tool"} ,'Tooling forecast template'!R6C6:R500C6,"<>Actual tool/equipment change") )
```

Basically, you calculate the SUMIF with an array of values as your criteria, then wrap that SUMIF in a SUM so that the multiple answers are added together.

This example is quite hard to read due to the long variable names.  Here's a simpler example, where you want to add up some numbers where the corresponding letter is either A or B...

The long way:

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B5, A1:A5, "A") + SUMIFS(B1:B5, A1:A5, "B")
```

The short way:

```
=SUM( SUMIFS(B1:B5, A1:A5, {"A","B"}) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the two SUMIFS together, its the same thing!

```
=SUMIFS('Tooling forecast template'!R6C17:R500C17,'Tooling forecast template'!R6C7:R500C7,"=Test Tool" ,'Tooling forecast template'!R6C6:R500C6,"<>Actual tool/equipment change") + SUMIFS('Tooling forecast template'!R6C17:R500C17,'Tooling forecast template'!R6C7:R500C7,"=Hard Tool" ,'Tooling forecast template'!R6C6:R500C6,"<>Actual tool/equipment change")
```

Comment: Thanks but that is what I am trying to avoid :)

Comment: The reason I want to avoid this is because I will add one more OR function into the SUMIFS and I dont like 4 SUMIFS :) I have this function 107 times! 4*107 = bad

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that A OR B is the same thing as NOT ((NOT A) and (NOT B)).  For example, sum the entries in A if B=1 or C=1 using SUMIFS:

```
=SUM(A1:A10) - SUMIFS(A1:A10,B1:B10,"<>0",C1:C10,"<>0")
```

You can achieve the same result with SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUM(A1:A10) - SUMPRODUCT(A1:A10,--(B1:B10<>0),--(C1:C10<>0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work as well?

Note:
    Assuming Col A houses values to be summed.
    Assuming Col B houses the tool types.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"hard tool"),SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"test tool"))
```

Comment: This does not work if the conditions come from different columns and there is overlap between the two.  Also, it is not very compact in general, especially if you have 20 categories to combine.